# Able to consistently pass the US B license test; what more is needed for a Danish amateur radio license?

Tags: license, europe

I need to cram the last bits for my exam - I don't know my competence level precisely, but I've passed the US B-license tests a bunch of times. Problem is I'm in Denmark - how should I cram for this so I'm not caught by some EU specific regulation?

Comment: Where in the EU are you? Europe's CEPT has unified syllabus for some of the classes, but it's up to CEPT countries to use it or not to use it. Furthermore, not all EU countries use the CEPT/ECO 3-class model and in 3-class countries not all classes match CEPT recommendations. Furthermore, to which US B-license tests are you referring to?

Comment: Those supplied by hamstudy.org . I'm in DK - thanks for your answer

Comment: Well hello there neighbor! I'm in the north of Germany!  It might be a good idea to actually put that information in your question itself, perhaps even in the title. Also did you contact for example [EDR](http://www.edr.dk/EDR-01/?Amat%C3%B8rradio___Hvordan_bliver_man_radioamat%C3%B8r) about this? In some countries, there are public question pools, in other countries there aren't. In some countries, there are published study guides, in others, there aren't. Now, my Danish isn't very good, but from what I could figure out, your B-level license is EU's CEPT Novice class.

Comment: So for some very general info, you should take a look at [ERC Report 32](http://www.erodocdb.dk/docs/doc98/official/pdf/ERCRep032.pdf). Let's hope someone else might give more useful info.

Comment: Yes, I am a member, but my mentor drove his bicycle into a streetlight and is in a coma. I'll look at CEPT Novice requirements.

Comment: Oh, well let's hope he recovers soon! :( Perhaps it would be a good idea to see if you can find someone else temporarily to help out in this quite unusual situation?

Comment: Yes, looks like I will have to do that. He's going to be spanked for not wearing a helmet.

Comment: You must have a local ham club somewhere nearby.  That is where I would start looking for advice for your specific area.